# Manipulate multiples HTML files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to manipulate more than one HTML file in the same script?
For example, i have a `<div id="div1">` on my index.html, and `<div id="div2">` in another HTML file inside of another folder.

What i trying to do is get the content of the second div and replace to my "div1", but the "traditional way" doesnt work:

```
function replaceDiv(){
    let div1 = document.querySelector('#div1')
    let div2 = document.querySelector('#div2')
    div1.innerHTML = div2
}
```

I'm new to programming, sorry if this is a dumb/obvious question haha

ps: both files have the link for the same script.

ps²: i know that i can manually write the string with innerHTML, but i wanna know if it's possible to do this

Comment: Am curious about the so called *"traditional way"*! Could elaborate more on that.

Comment: with "traditional way" i just meant the normal method that we use for just 1 file, as well as the code I wrote in the question itself  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why this doesn't work

The [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object in JavaScript is representative of the currently rendered page's content, it can only exist when the page that loads this script is actively being rendered.

A web browser can only render one HTML file at a time (e.g. either `index.html` or `other.html`). Say `#div1` is in `index.html` and `#div2` is in `other.html`; the script can only see that one of these div elements exists since the `document` is scoped to the current page.

This is the same reason that you can reuse ids across multiple HTML files on the same website with no unexpected behavior.

#### Alternate Solution

Store this data (InnerHTML/the snippet needs to be shared) in the script itself since that can be requested on each page individually.

Comment: This is a great answer! The only thing I'd add is that this behavior is intentional design. If any webpage could edit another page, then there'd be major security concerns (imagine if a scam site you accidentally visited could edit the HTML of your bank login).

Comment: *"A web browser can only render one HTML file at a time..."* [`iFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) did you hear  that ?!